# Best practice: Sending Twitter access token to server

Tags: reactjs, twitter, azure-functions

I am using NextAuth to login users using Twitter. This works fine and I receive the AccessToken and the Token Secret on the client side. However I need to query the Twitter API on the server side to get the logged in user profile information. Therefore I need to submit the AccessToken and Token Secret to the server with every request.

Should I combine the AccessToken and Token Secret into one string and send it as part of the Authorization Header parameter and parse it on the server side?

Security wise what would be the recommended way to send the access token information to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a best practice, but I'd say there are some thoughts that would argue against some of the solutions available.

First of, from a terminology standpoint, using the Authorization header would seem to be a misuse of its defined purpose ([RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)):

> "... allows a user agent to authenticate itself with an origin server"

And:

> "Its value consists of credentials containing the authentication
> information of the user agent for the realm of the resource being
> requested."

In this case, that's not what you're doing - the supplied credentials are not for the requested resource (action, rather), but information needed to by the requested action.

Secondly, I'd refrain from including any of the credentials in the path, for the reason that it's *usually* not treated as sensitive information from a logging perspective.

Since you're thinking security, I just assume you're enforcing HTTPS with your Functions. I also assume you're using `HttpTrigger` since you're saying you need to send the credentials with each request.

As I see it, you have 3 options:

- Put it in a custom header (not Authorization)
- Put it as query parameters
- Put it in the body

Personal guidelines for the 3:

- Header values as "meta" associated with the request that won't fit as query (or in URL).
- Query parameters as parameterized "meta" associated with the resource/action.
- Body as information to be used in processing an action (e.g. the state of a resource to be created).

So... I'd put it in the body.

All 3 options are secure (or well, as secure as the sever is configured). My best guess is that the body is the least logged information on a server. Primarily because the body can vary greatly in size, and would take up a lot of space if all request bodies were to be logged. Some servers might log the full URL (including query parameters), which is definitely a thing to take into consideration. Whether Azure does this "behind the scenes" for Functions, I don't know. The path is available as clear text via Application Insights, the query parameters are as far as I know not shown anywhere, unless explicitly written to the log by the implementation.

In any case, base64 encoding the information could be a last "good practice" step regardless of your choice, for example as "value:value" like BasicAuth.